# Flutter - How to change the color of a disabled checkbox?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I want to change the color of the disabledCheckbox. I have passed `NULL` to the `onChanged` method to disable the checkbox. However, the `disableColor` from `ThemeData` is not being used in the checkbox.

What should I do change the disabled color of Checkbox?

**FILE: ** LIGHT THEME

```dart
get _lightTheme => ThemeData(
      disabledColor: Colors.red,
      useMaterial3: true,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      primaryColor: AppPalette.primaryColorLight,
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:
            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppPalette.primaryColorLight),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
      )),
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        suffixIconColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA6A7A8), fontSize: 14),
        errorBorder: kErrorInputBorder,
        focusedErrorBorder: kFocusedErrorInputBorder,
        focusedBorder: kFocusedInputBorder,
        disabledBorder: kDisabledInputBorder,
        enabledBorder: kEnabledInputBorder,
        border: kDefaultInputBorder,
      ),
      checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
              AppPalette.primaryColorLight.withOpacity(0.25)),
          checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
          fillColor:
              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppPalette.primaryColorLight)),
    );
```

**FILE: ** AppCheckBox.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class AppCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool enabled;
  final String title;
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onChanged;
  final bool initialValue;

  const AppCheckBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    this.enabled = true,
    this.onChanged,
    this.initialValue = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppCheckBox> createState() => _AppCheckBoxState();
}

class _AppCheckBoxState extends State<AppCheckBox> {
  bool value = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    value = widget.initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Checkbox(
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            value: value,
            onChanged: !widget.enabled
                ? null
                : (_) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (!mounted) return;

                      value = !value;
                    });

                    if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                      widget.onChanged!(value);
                    }
                  }),
        Flexible(
          child: Text(widget.title,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use unselectedWidgetColor

```
ThemeData(
        unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      ),
```

To change it inside the checkbox you can add

```
side: BorderSide(color: Colors.Orange),
```